# Discord.js. I try to make a kick log but when i kick someone it isn't logging

Tags: javascript, discord.js

This is my code

```js
bot.on("guildMemberRemove", async (member) => {
  const tlog = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
    limit: 1,
    type: "MEMBER_KICK",
  });
  const klog = tlog.entries.first();
  const { executor, target } = klog;
  const rs = tlog.entries.first().reason;
  const emb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Új KICK!") //New Kick Title
    .addField("Kickelt neve", target.user) //The kicked member name
    .addField("Kickelő neve", executor) //The member who kicked the other member
    .addField("Indok", rs) //Reason
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor(15158332)
  addToLog(emb); 
})
```

addToLog Function

```js
const channell = "792743591017316413"; //Channel id
function addToLog(message){
    const szoba = bot.channels.cache.get(channell); //szoba means room
    return szoba.send(message);
};
```

I looked more websites for the solution, but I completely copy the code and nothing happens.

Comment: Hello, please add the function definition for `addToLog` that would be the important part here.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console, post those too, those are also important when debugging.

Comment: @Rodentman87. I didn't get any errors

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [docs for TextChannel.send()](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send). It returns a promise, you need to resolve this promise with either an `await` or `.then()`.

Comment: If you can, can you send me a code about how do you mean?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Try looking at the docs on MDN here about promises in JS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code into:

```
    function addToLog(message, channel) {
      return channel.send(message);
    };

    bot.on("guildMemberRemove", async (member) => {
    const tlog = await member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
      limit: 1,
      type: "MEMBER_KICK",
    });
   const klog = tlog.entries.first();
   const { executor, target } = klog;
   const rs = tlog.entries.first().reason;
   const channell = "Your channel ID"; //Channel id
   const szoba = bot.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id === channell); 
   const emb = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Új KICK!") //New Kick Title
    .addField("Kickelt neve", target.user) //The kicked member name
    .addField("Kickelő neve", executor) //The member who kicked the other 
     member
    .addField("Indok", rs) //Reason
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor(15158332)
   addToLog(emb, szoba); 
})
```

I used a second parameter `channel`, which in this case is your `szoba`. So you initialize the two constants `channell` and `szoba` outside of the function. Then you provide a message and your constant `szoba` (thats the channel you want your log been sent to). Inside of the function `addToLog()` you simply want the provided message sent to the provided channel (`szoba`).

Comment: Hello! I have an error: {Cannot read property 'send' of undefined}

Comment: Yes! Here you are >

`const channell = "793205853569286155";
const szoba = bot.channels.cache.get(channell);

function addToLog(message, channel){
    return szoba.send(message);
};
`

Comment: @Dóczi make sure you copy my code without changing anything ^^ It has to be `return channel.send(message);` inside your `addToLog()` function.

Comment: I completely copy your code and paste it, I don't change anything, and it has the same error.

Comment: Please send me a screenshot of your code.

Comment: Okay I will try how to solve it give me a moment and please delete your screenshot. Everybody can see your token!

Comment: Thank you! Don't worry I regenerate it

Comment: @Dóczi I edited my code example above. Should work now! For me it works.

Comment: {Szoba is not defined} for me

Comment: Same problem again

Comment: Oh I just saw that you implemented your code into the `guildMemberRemove` event. You have to implement the code into your kick command code ^^

Comment: I don't have kick command. It just log to a text channel when somebody kick somebody